# how to know whether a custom link is being used in a sandbox or not?

Tags: custom

I need to delete a custom link which is a home custom link. But i am not sure that it is being used or not . Please provide me a solution.

Comment: Are you trying to find the number of clicks the link gets?

Comment: yes!!! You are right !!

Comment: Doh. I thought you meant literally unused (not linked to any layout).

Answer (score 0):

I would change the link to something you can track using something like bitly.

If you need to get that data from Salesforce, it will cost you quite a bit for the forensics logs.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Interpreting-the-Forensic-Logs&language=en_US